# How do I use a storyboard Dynamic Prototypes TableViewCell to format SearchDisplayController results

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, searchdisplaycontroller

I created TableViewController subclass and used it with a storyboard. I created 1 Dynamic Prototype and used its Identifier value in the subclass. It works and displays the cells as it shows in the storyboard. But when I added the searchDisplayController and made the TableViewController the delegate and datasource, it displays the corrct search results, but the format of the TableViewCells no longer followed the storyboard prototype. Code I used below. How can I make it follow the prototype?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Contact Cell";
    static NSString *sCellID = @"Contact Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellID];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {            
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:sCellID];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {            
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
        }


    // ask NSFetchedResultsController for the NSMO at the row in question
    Contact *contact = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Then configure the cell using it ...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1234_profile.png"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [contact.lastName stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@",contact.firstName];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", contact.occupation, contact.companyName];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use

```
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellID];
```

instead of

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellID];
```

Then a prototype cell of storyboard is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom cell by sub classing UITableViewCell. Then you have to configure the appearance of the cell in layoutSubviews.

This does not solve your problem that you want to design your cells in Storyboards. I think that the integration of the UISearchControl into Storyboards is still a little clumsy and that there is no better solution.

Comment: I was also planning on the custom cell. But wanted to see if there is an easier way. Thanks for your posted answer.